# React-Native - iOS - CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "OpenSSL-Universal":

Tags: react-native, podfile, flipper

I want to run a "pod install". I get the warning "[!] use_flipper is deprecated, use the flipper_configuration option in the use_react_native function"

So i replace the line "use_flipper!" to "use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0' })" in my Podfile.

After this i removed the lock-File and run a "pod install" again.

I get the error

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "OpenSSL-Universal":
  In Podfile:
    Flipper-Folly (= 2.3.0) was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on
      OpenSSL-Universal (= 1.0.2.20)

    OpenSSL-Universal (= 1.1.1100)

Specs satisfying the `OpenSSL-Universal (= 1.1.1100), OpenSSL-Universal (= 1.0.2.20)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

My deployment target for iOS is "13.0". I have changed my deployment target but without any solution. Can someone help me?

My podfile:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '13.0'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

target 'XXApp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  pod 'react-native-beacons-manager', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-beacons-manager'

  target 'XXAppTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0' })

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

Comment: share pod file.

Comment: I updated my initial post

Answer (score 6):

add this line in your pod file:

```
pod 'OpenSSL-Universal'
```

replace this line

```
  use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0' })
```

with

```
  use_flipper!
```

delete podfile.lock and pods folder,
then run

```
pod install
```

Comment: Thank but without solution. 

"[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "OpenSSL-Universal":
  In Podfile:
    OpenSSL-Universal (= 1.1.1100)

    OpenSSL-Universal (~> 1.0.2.20)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies: `OpenSSL-Universal (~> 1.0.2.20), OpenSSL-Universal (= 1.1.1100)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
"

Comment: I run "pod install --repo-update"

Comment: I have done this. with the following error. I answer my question to show you the formatted logs

Comment: remove version as shown above try again.

Comment: which version are you talking about exactly? So what exactly should I do?

Comment: pod 'OpenSSL-Universal' only this not with version

Comment: I have updated answer above see

Comment: The error with "open-SSL" is gone, but the error with " Flipper (= 0.125.0) was resolved to 0.125.0, which depends on
      Flipper-Folly (~> 2.6)" is always there

Comment: see the answer for use_flipper!

Comment: I dont have errors, only warning yet.
"[!] use_flipper is deprecated, use the flipper_configuration option in the use_react_native function

[!] There are duplicate dependencies on `OpenSSL-Universal` in `Podfile`:

- OpenSSL-Universal
- OpenSSL-Universal (= 1.1.1100)
"

Comment: If there is no error and code run successfully then it is ok.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250527/discussion-between-isabo-and-jatin-bhuva). I have another question about this.

Comment: For anyone seeing this, the above worked for me except I did not need to add `pod 'OpenSSL-Universal'` to my Podifile.

Comment: working fine after I changed in my pod file

pod 'OpenSSL-Universal'

  target 'hTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  # use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0' }) # update this part
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
   flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
end